# Is the database table "field_revision_body" used in a core module or can I just drop it?

Tags: 7, entities, database

I recently installed the revisioning module and now im cleaning it up and uninstalling it, but it seem to have created a bunch of field_revision_field_ tables in my database. Since it creates another table for every field you have, it creates alot of mess. I uninstalled the revisioning module, but these tables still stayed. I was wondering if I can just drop these? Also i see there is a field_revision_body table, but i dont know if it was generated by the revisioning module. So im asking if anyone knows what this table is used for? I tried deleting it, but i get an error when editing a node. So it must be used for something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both tables (`field_data_*` and `field_revision_*`) are added and used by the field SQL storage module in core. The existence of both tables make it possible to store revisions of field data. There's no way to use that storage system without both `data_*` and `revision_*` tables.

So don't delete it :)

There are modules out there defining alternative storage systems without using revision tables (e.g. [Field SQL norevisions](https://drupal.org/project/field_sql_norevisions)) but I'm not sure how difficult it would be to convert an existing database to use that system.

Comment: thanks clive.. but i found out the hard way.. had to restore multiple times and realized we need the revision_ tables. =( ...